# How to Open a File Geodatabase with ogr?

Tags: python, ogr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access feature classes in File Geodatabases with python and gdal?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/how-to-access-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabases-with-python-and-gdal)

I have installed:

python-2.7.msi

GDAL-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.exe

```
import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FileGDB")
print driver
```

I receive None

Do I need to install something extra to open GDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to build GDAL with FileGDB support.

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB

An alternative is to use OSGEO4W.  It automatically takes care of all your dependencies under Windows.

https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: I saw first link but I don't now how to use this instrutions...Is possible to download a compiled GDAL with FileGDB?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The easiest thing to do is download OSGEO4W.  There is a very good procedure here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis

Answer (score 1):

For those using OSX Lion, here are some good step-by-step instructions: https://gist.github.com/2005158