# ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB') returns None

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I installed:

- gdal-110-1600-x64-core.msi
- GDAL-1.10.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi
- gdal-110-1600-x64-filegdb.msi

from [www.gisinternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-10-mapserver-6-2.zip)

I can open my gdb on the command line:

```
C:\data>ogrinfo --version
GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24

C:\data>ogrinfo data.gdb
INFO: Open of `data.gdb'
  using driver `FileGDB' successful.
```

In "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins" I have a file named ogr_FileGDB.dll

However, when I execute the following code:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL" + ';' + os.environ['PATH']    
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH'] = "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdalplugins"
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-data"

print os.path.exists(os.environ['PATH'].split(';')[0])
print os.path.exists(os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH'])
print os.path.exists(os.environ['GDAL_DATA'])

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')
print driver
```

I get the following output:

```
True
True
True
None
```

It looks like the FileGDB driver does not work with Python.
Did I miss something to install?

Is it possible to print all available drivers of GDAL in Python?

p.s. A similar questions was asked already: ["How to Open a File Geodatabase with ogr? [duplicate]"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34985/how-to-open-a-file-geodatabase-with-ogr). It was marked as duplicate to ["How to access feature classes in file geodatabases with Python and GDAL?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210623012907/https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/how-to-access-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabases-with-python-and-gdal). However, I think there ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB') clearly works.

Comment: problem of improper installation, because the FileGDB driver work with Python, even with GDAL 1.9

Comment: what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: use the Python gdal module of [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) and copy/paste ogr_FileGDB.dll from GDAL