# Listing every layer in Geopackage using Fiona

Tags: python, geopackage, fiona

I loaded a GeoPackage into Python and I can't figure out how to list all the layers in the file. How do I do that?

Input: GeoPackage loaded into Python.

Desired output: A list of the layers in the GeoPackage.

Code for connecting to GeoPackage:

```
import geopandas as gpd    
gpkg = 'path/to.gpkg'
# Missing: list layers
```

Comment: What code did you use to load the Geopackage into Python?

Comment: Is was less efficient than the code in the answer lol

Comment: That looks like it just sets a string variable to a full path name representing the GeoPackage file.  I thought you must have been creating a GeoPackage object using something, and just didn't know how to access a property with its layers .

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255232/2856

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple to do this using [Fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/). I prefer using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) to read the Geopackage, and then Fiona to list the layers:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona

gpkg = 'path/to.gpkg'
layers = fiona.listlayers(gpkg)
```

You'll end up with the layer names as a list.

Answer (score 2):

Using the GeoDjango API you can do the following:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource

gpkg = DataSource('path/to.gpkg')
layers = [layer.name for layer in gpkg]
```