# Working with NHDPlus data in GDB file format using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, ogr, fiona

I am trying to work with the [NHDPlus High Resolution dataset](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHDPlusHR/National/GDB/) from the USGS. Looking at the [documentation](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/ofr20191096), there should be all sorts of data table available as well as mapping layers but the only thing I can access from the GDB file are the following layers:

```
Input: 

import fiona
fiona.listlayers(r'.\NHDPlus_H_National_Release_1_GDB.zip')

Output: 
['NHDPlusConnect',
'NHDPlusGageSmooth',
'WBDHU12',
'NonNetworkNHDFlowline',
'NetworkNHDFlowline',
'NHDWaterbody',
'NHDPoint',
'NHDPlusWall',
'NHDPlusSink',
'NHDPlusGage',
'NHDPlusCatchment',
'NHDPlusBoundaryUnit',
'NHDLine',
'NHDArea',
'NHDPlusFlow']
```

How can I access the data tables that are also in this file?

Edit: I expect to see the following features and table as described in pages 5 and 6 of the user documentation previously referenced:

[image: Table 2 from page 5 of User Documentation]
[[image: Table 3 from page 6 of User Documentation 4]

Comment: From my understanding ESRI has understandably and purposely made it difficult to manipulate .gdb files in open source software. I'm unsure what you are trying to accomplish, but I'd recommend taking a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255138/reading-the-names-of-geodatabase-file-layers-in-python) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis) post. If that doesn't point you in the right direction, please edit and explain your question further.

Comment: @Binx, I have edited the question to show what I except to find but have been unable to access.

Comment: Is there a subset of the data to download? I dont want to have to download 26 GB to test with

Comment: @BERA if you go to the following link, the beta version is broken into individual Hydrological units. https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHDPlusHR/Beta/GDB/

Comment: I've downloaded `https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHDPlusHR/Beta/GDB/NHDPLUS_H_0101_HU4_GDB.zip` and find 85 layers with fiona.listlayers

Comment: @BERA, I just checked up on these data and the national release combines all the features and removes most of the constituent tables yet the USGS only mentions this in an article posted elsewhere.? I see where I have been going wrong. Thank you for your help. https://www.usgs.gov/national-hydrography/news/usgs-announces-nhdplus-hr-national-release-1

Comment: I think both the Esri and Open GBD libraries expect the zipfile contents to be extracted to a local filesystem. Direct access into variable length records within a zipfile is nightmarish.